# Setting children in defaultProps

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a React component that contains some child components. I would like it to have a default set of children, if its element is created without specifying children (i.e. `<MyContainerComponent ... />` should be equivalent to `<MyContainerComponent ...><!-- some default child elements --></MyContainerComponent>`).

From https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.14.8/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L135, I understand that `props.children` will be `undefined` if no children are specified. Thus, I would like to rely on this and set `children` in the `defaultProps` of `MyContainerComponent`.

I am not sure, however, if I am coupling my decision too much with React's implementation (i.e. by design, as a user of React, is it acceptable to treat `children` just like any other prop that would be undefined if you did not explicitly define it). All other materials I read on `children` treat is as either a single element, or an array, but not potentially `undefined`.

I'd really appreciate a more experienced opinion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The React project hasn't done a great job of documenting how `props.children` is treated, but I would say that:

> it [is] acceptable to treat children just like any other prop that would be undefined if you did not explicitly define it

References:

[Comments by Sebastian Markbåge](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/6018#issuecomment-182660779):

> The type of `this.props.children` is whatever your component's `propTypes` says it is.

And:

> We recommend that most of the time you use the general `ReactNode` type for your `this.props.children`.

Where the definition of [`ReactNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html) includes `undefined`.

My interpretation is that `undefined` is a valid value for `props.children` and should be the default in general. But note that with JSX even whitespace might affect the value:

```js
<MyContainerComponent> </MyContainerComponent>
```

All of this being said, as indicated by the linked GitHub issue I'm trying to get this better documented so the API contract is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Set default props for children using `getDefaultProps`. If react changes the definition of empty props === `undefined`, they will also do so in the `getDefaultProps` life cycle method ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/0orn9hyy/4/)):

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
        children: <span>default child</span> // set children in default props
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>I am a { this.props.children }</div>; // if we have children use them, if not use default from state
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />, // without children
  document.getElementById('container1')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent>non a default child</Parent>, // with children
  document.getElementById('container2')
);
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid using state though, if possible. Also, the question still stands, should I reasonably expect `props.children` to be still be `undefined` in this case, instead of, say, an empty array, in future versions of React?

Comment: As `children` are a prop, they can be handled by `getDefaultProps`. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.createElement` as default value for your `children` props
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

example:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { element } from 'prop-types'

export class Example extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = { children: element }
  static defaultProps = { children: React.createElement('div') }

  render () {
    const { children } = this.props

    return <div className='parent'>{children}</div>
  }
}
```